# Query execution time difference?

Tags: plsqldeveloper

I have a query manually like this:

```
 SELECT 
    to_char( to_date('29-Jul-12 22:25:11','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS')- SYSDATE ) 
 FROM DUAL
```

I need to show output only like `HH24:MM:SS`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT trunc(MOD((SYSDATE - to_date('29-Jul-12 22:25:11', 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS')) * 24, 24)) || ':' ||
       trunc(MOD((SYSDATE - to_date('29-Jul-12 22:25:11', 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS')) * 24 * 60, 60)) || ':' ||
       trunc(MOD((SYSDATE - to_date('29-Jul-12 22:25:11', 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS')) * 24 * 60 * 60, 60)) Time
FROM   dual
```

Answer (score 0):

write function that takes your stamp date and returns varchar2 (the value like "HH24:MI:SS")

```
    create or replace Function Get_Difference(i_Stamp_Date date) return varchar2 is
  v_Result varchar2(8);
begin    
  v_Result := Round(mod((sysdate - i_Stamp_Date) * 24, 24)) || ':' ||
              Round(mod((sysdate - i_Stamp_Date) * 1440, 60)) || ':' ||
              Round(mod((sysdate - i_Stamp_Date) * 86400, 60));

  return v_Result;
end;
```

and then you can call it like:

```
SELECT Get_Difference(to_date('29-Jul-12 22:25:11','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS'))  FROM DUAL
```

and enjoy it!